# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat

Tags: angular, github

i´m new in this world, so i´m in basics. I´m doing a project for my studies and i´m having a problem when i want to run ng serve.

**An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\lucas\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ProyectoIntegrador_CragarisLucas\ProyectoIntegrador_CragarisLucas\ProyectoIntegrador_CragarisLucas'See "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-e0RyVZ\angular-errors.log" for further details.**

[error in vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTt3g.png)
[error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq5BT.png)

I´ll leave the project in github so you can possibly help me. I´ll really thank you.

https://github.com/Lucasalexisc/ProyectoIntegrador_CragarisLucas

Comment: can you try `npm install` ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I put in the angular.json file the line : `node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Instead of : `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

So I misspelt `node_modules`.

If you had used the same method, you have to check the directory you put.

Answer (score 0):

try to handle it by removing `'./'` before your bootstrap link in angular.json

like this:

```
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

and make sure that it is placed before your css link.